# 'decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Round'

Tags: c#

new to C# and hit this compile error when attempting to use the Round method for the first time.  Any ideas?  Thanks:

```
private void totalPoundsTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = textBoxes[1];
    decimal numericValue = textBoxNumberCheck(textBox, 0M, 22046M,false);
    if (numericValue >= 0)
        ***weight.Kilos =  decimal.Round(numericValue / 2.2046M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);***
        UpdateBoxValues();
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: @PeterDuniho There is. Look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.round(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @S: well, I'll be a monkey's uncle...wonder what the point of that was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use Math.Round instead.

```
weight.Kilos = Math.Round(numericValue / 2.2046, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Answer (score 8):

I bet you have .Net Core project version prior to 2.0. `Decimal.Round()` method was missing in .Net Core prior to 2.0 but is now available. Check this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/6111) for the details.

So you could fix your problem either by upgrading to .Net Core 2.0 or by using `Math.Round()` as Sunil suggests.

Comment: Thanks, I have followed the advice to use Math.Round, but will update .Net Core as it may cause confusion with other things.  I just want to thank you all for your prompt and helpful responses.  It is very much appreciated.

Comment: I got as far as the download page but wasn't sure which link I needed. 
 I have a 64 bit Windows machine. 
 Don't want to mess anything up. 
 Could you advise?  Thanks https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archives/2.0.4-download.md   Wasn't sure what SDK Binaries Runtime Installer Runtime Binaries were.

Comment: Select [64-bit SDK installer](https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/9/3/293BC432-348C-4D1C-B628-5AC8AB7FA162/dotnet-sdk-2.1.3-win-x64.exe)

Answer (score 2):

Use `Math.Round` instead:

```
private void totalPoundsTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = textBoxes[1];
    decimal numericValue = textBoxNumberCheck(textBox, 0M, 22046M,false);
    if (numericValue >= 0)
        weight.Kilos = Math.Round(numericValue / 2.2046M, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

    UpdateBoxValues();
}
```